# Is it worth precomputing the conditional in a for loop?

Tags: objective-c, c

1. Is there a difference between the following two code blocks in terms of the resulting machine code when using the `llvm` or `gcc` compilers?
2. When is this optimization actually worthwhile, if ever?

Not optimized:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {
    //do some work
}
```

Optimized:

```
int count = array.count;
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    //do some work
}
```

**EDIT**: I should point out that `array` is immutable and `array.count` doesn't change during the loop's execution.

Comment: Often it's not needed as the compiler will most likely do that optimization anyway. But the only way to be sure is to test both ways and measure. As for the resulting machine code, you can easily check yourself, both clang and gcc have flags to output assembler files, and you could always disassemble the executable if nothing else.

Comment: In this case, there is a message sent to an object, I doubt the compiler interferes with it, so my guess would be that the `count` method will be called on each iteration. However, it's probably a very cheap call. The best way in this particular case would be to use fast enumeration on the array.

Comment: "array is immutable and array.count doesn't change" -- I don't know Objective-C, whether "immutable" is a property that the compiler understands, but for optimization purposes it doesn't matter whether or not `array.count` changes, it matters whether the compiler can prove to itself that `array.count` doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You really need to check it yourself. My guess is that there *is* a difference in the emitted code, but it might depend on compiler and compiler options, and it certainly can depend on the definition of `array`.
2. Nearly never, on the assumption that evaluating `array.count` is nearly always insignificant compared with "some work". The way to measure it, though, is to use a profiler (or equivalent) and observe what proportion of your program's runtime is spent at that line of code. Provided the profiler is accurate, that's the *most* you could hope to gain by changing it.

Suppose `array.count` is something really slow, that you happen to know will always return the same result but the compiler doesn't know that. Then it might be worth manually hoisting it. `strlen` gets used as an example. It's debateable how often `strlen` is *actually* slow in practice, but easy to manufacture examples likely to run slower than they need to:

```
char some_function(char a) {
    return (a * 2 + 1) & 0x3F;
}

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); ++i) {
    ptr[i] = some_function(ptr[i]); // faster than strlen for long enough strings.
}
```

You and I know that `some_function` never returns 0, and hence the length of the string never changes. The compiler might not see the definition of `some_function`, and even if it does see the definition might not realize that its non-zero-returningness is important.

Answer (score 1):

The Steve Jessop answer is a good one. I just want to add:

Personally, I always use optimized version. It's just in my set of good practices to remove every constant component out of the loop. It's not much work and it makes code cleaner. It's not "premature optimization" and it does not introduce any problems or tradeoffs. It makes debugging easier (stepping). And it could potentially make the code faster. So it's a no-brainer to me.